# How do I query inside a JSONB column when all values have the same json-like structure?

Tags: postgresql, json, jsonb, json-path

In a postgresql database, I have a table with 2 columns:

Column1 is of type VARCHAR and contains multiple rows of ids in this format: ID1123312

Column2 is of type JSONB and contains multiple rows of jsons which have this structure:

```
{
    "a": [
        {
            "a1": "2022-01-01",
            "a2": "2026-01-31",
            "a3": 1
        }
    ],
    "b": [
        {
            "b1": "J",
            "b2": "1231342138adc2fehj3j21321321321kjk1423j32k9"
        }
    ],
    "c": [
        {
            "c1-1": "2021-02-01",
            "c1-2": "2021-01-01"
        },
        {
            "c2-1": "2021-04-01",
            "c2-2": "2021-03-01"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to build a SELECT statement to return the row above giving the value of b2  (1231342138adc2fehj3j21321321321kjk1423j32k9) as an input parameter.

Something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE [Column2 contains b which contains b2 which has value '1231342138adc2fehj3j21321321321kjk1423j32k9'] ;
```

OR just:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE [value '1231342138adc2fehj3j21321321321kjk1423j32k9' exists in row from Column2 ]
```

I just don't know how to give this instruction.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_path_exists` along with a JSON path query

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE jsonb_path_exists(t.jsonColumn, '$.b[*].b2 ? (@ == "1231342138adc2fehj3j21321321321kjk1423j32k9")')
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jTJvmrvB)

The `[*]` in this path means "any array element" and `? (@ == ...)` mean a predicate that the value at that path must equal your value.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works! Could you tell me how to look for 2 or more values as well instead of just one, please?

Comment: Depends on your exact requirements. Do you want to look for one of two `b2` values, or are you looking for different properties? I suggest you take a good read of the documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH and create a new question if you don't understand it